# Spaces taken up by iBooks is not showing on iCloud?

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, backup

I recently deleted iPhone backup on iCloud which was occupying almost 4gb out of my 5gb basic iCloud storage. Since then when I check my iCloud account it shows that iBooks 3.8 data but only showing 1.1gb total on iCloud Drive.

I’m using iPad to read iBooks and All my academic books are stored on iBooks. I’m really worried that Apple may delete my iBook books. This happens to me once. Is this a software issue or what?

Note: also I noticed though I have enough space showing on the iCloud as shown in the image, my WhatsApp backup progress is stucked!

[image]

Comment: Are you using iBooks both for books bought in the iTunes store and for PDFs you've added yourself?

Comment: @nohilside yes. Most of my books are my academic PDFs.